# DHCP Request / Reply. (Python) DHCP клиент / сервер не глотает фейковый пакет

Tags: python, сервер, сокет, client, dhcp

Нужно на питоне создать скрипт который будет эмитировать некоторые DHCP пакеты. При этом когда пускаю в сеть DHCP Discovery роутер (TP_Link) на это не отвечает, просто игнорирует. Насколько я знаю поле checksum не проверяется ни сервером ни клиентом, поэтому оставляю его пустым

```
import socket
import binascii
import struct
import uuid
import random

class DHCPGen:

    def __init__(self):
        self.dataHead = []


    def dhcpdiscoveer(self):
        self.dataHead = [
            b'\x01\x01'                                                 # Message Type
            b'\x06\x00',                                                # Request Type
            struct.pack('!I', random.randrange(0, 2147483647, 1)),      # Transaction ID /20
            b'\x00\x00',                                                # elasted
            b'\x00\x00',                                                # flags
            b'\x00\x00\x00\x00',                                        # You (Client) IP address
            b'\x00\x00\x00\x00',                                        # You (Client) IP address
            b'\x00\x00\x00\x00',                                        # Next server IP address
            b'\x00\x00\x00\x00',                                        # Relay agent IP address
            struct.pack('!6B', *[0, 227, 197, 187, 99, 255]),                    # Client MAC
            struct.pack('!5H', *[0 for i in range(0, 5)]),              # Client HW address padding
            struct.pack('!32H', *[0 for i in range(0, 32)]),            # Server host name (not given 0x00(64)) /29
            struct.pack('!64H', *[0 for i in range(0, 64)]),            # Boot file name (not given 0x00(128))
            b'\x63\x82\x53\x63',                                        # Magic cookie DHCP
                #options
            b'\x35\x01\x01',                                            # (53) DHCP Mes Type: Discover (1)
            b'\x3d\x07\x01'+struct.pack('!6B', *[0, 227, 197, 187, 99, 255]),    # (61) Client identifier /33
            b'\x32\x04'+struct.pack('!4B', *[192, 168, 1, 128]),        # (50) Requested IP address
            b'\x0c',
            struct.pack('!B', len(socket.gethostname())),               # (12) Host Name (len)
            bytes(socket.gethostname(), 'ASCII'),                       # (12) Host Name (text)
            b'\x3c\x08\x4d\x53\x46\x54\x20\x35\x2e\x30',                # (60) Vendor class ident
            b'\x37\x0e\x01\x03\x06\x0f\x1f\x21\x2b\x2c\x2e\x2f\x77\x79\xf9\xfc', # Parameter Request List
            b'\xff'                                                     # end
        ]

        return self.dataHead

    def __getLocMac(self):
       locmac = []
       for i in [("%X" % uuid.getnode())[i:i+2] for i in range(0, 12, 2)]:
           if i == '':
               continue
           locmac.append(int(i, 16))
       if len(locmac) < 6:
           locmac.insert(0, int('00', 16))
       return locmac

    def __getLocIp(self):
        ip = [int(i) for i in socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()).split('.')]
        return ip

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dhcp = DHCPGen()

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    sock.bind(('', 68))
    sock.sendto(b''.join(dhcp.dhcpdiscoveer()), ('<broadcast>', 67))
    sock.close()
```

Точно такая же ситуация и с ответом на DHCP Discover. DHCP клиент не отвечает request-ом на offer.

Запуская скрипт подключаюсь с ноута (Windows) к сети, Wireshark показывает, клиент отправил Discover, скрипт ловит пакет, парсит, генерирует Offer, но Offer остаётся проигнорированным. Однако ответ от реального dhcp ловится и успешно глотается.

```
import socket
import binascii
import struct
import uuid
import random

class DHCPGen:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dataHead = []

    def offer(self, parsedData):
        self.dataHead = [
            parsedData['sourceMac'],
            struct.pack('!6B', *self.__getLocMac()),
            b'\x08\x00\x45\x00',
            b'\x02\x40',
            struct.pack('!H', random.randrange(0, 65535, 1)),
            b'\x00\x00\x64\x11\x00\x00',
            struct.pack('!4B', *[192, 168, 0, 108]),
            struct.pack('!4B', *[192, 168, 0, 220]),
            b'\x00\x43\x00\x44',
            b'\x02\x2c',
            b'\x0a\x80',
                # DHCP
            b'\x02',
            b'\x01\x06\x00',
            parsedData['transaction'],
            b'\x00\x00\x00\x00',
            b'\x00\x00\x00\x00',                        # Client IP addr
            struct.pack('!4B', *[192, 168, 0, 220]),    # You (client) ip addr
            b'\x00\x00\x00\x00',
            b'\x00\x00\x00\x00',
            parsedData['sourceMac'],
            struct.pack('!5H', *[0 for i in range(0, 5)]),  # Client HW address padding
            struct.pack('!32H', *[0 for i in range(0, 32)]),  # Server host name (not given 0x00(64)) /29
            struct.pack('!64H', *[0 for i in range(0, 64)]),  # Boot file name (not given 0x00(128))
            b'\x63\x82\x53\x63',
            b'\x35\x01\x02',                                  # (53) Message type 2 offer
            b'\x36\x04'+struct.pack('!4B', *[192, 168, 0, 108]),  # (54) DHCP Server IP
            b'\x33\x04\x00\x00\x1c\x20',                         # (51) Lease Time
            b'\x01\x04\xff\xff\xff\x00',                         # (1) Subnet Mask
            b'\x03\x04'+struct.pack('!4B', *[192, 168, 0, 108]),  # (3) Router IP
            b'\x06\x04'+struct.pack('!4B', *[192, 168, 0, 108]),  # (6) DNS server
            b'\xff',
            struct.pack('!274B', *[0 for i in range(0, 274)])
        ]
        length = len(b''.join(self.dataHead)) - 14
        self.dataHead[3] = struct.pack('!H', length)
        self.dataHead[9] = struct.pack('!H', length - 20)

        return self.dataHead

    def parseHeader(self, data):
        parsedData = {
            'destMac' : data[0:6],
            'sourceMac' : data[6:12],
            'typeip' : data[12:15],
            'protoData' : data[14:16],
            'clientMac' : data[70:76],
            'transaction' : data[46:50]
        }
        return parsedData


    def __getLocMac(self):
        locmac = []
        for i in [("%X" % uuid.getnode())[i:i+2] for i in range(0, 12, 2)]:
            if i == '':
                continue
            locmac.append(int(i, 16))
        if len(locmac) < 6:
            locmac.insert(0, int('00', 16))
        return locmac

    def __getLocIp(self):
        ip = [int(i) for i in socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()).split('.')]
        return ip

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dhcp = DHCPGen()

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(0x0003))
    sock.bind(('eth0', 0))
    sock.settimeout(20)
    while True:
        try:
            mes = sock.recvfrom(1024)
            data = mes[0]
            if binascii.hexlify(data[14:16]) != b'4500' or struct.unpack('!H', data[16:18])[0] < 280 or binascii.hexlify(data[23:24]) != b'11' or binascii.hexlify(data[282:285]) != b'350101':
                continue
            print(data)
            parsed = dhcp.parseHeader(data)
            print('__________________')
            reply = b''.join(dhcp.offer(parsed))
            sock.send(reply)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error: '+str(e))

    sock.close()
```

Что в этих заголовках не так? Почему реальные ни клиент ни сервер на них не отвечают?